# workDays and different hours for different professionals with angular schedule syncfusion

Tags: html, angular, typescript, schedule, syncfusion

I have a very dynamic schedule, where I will have professionals who attend on different days where on that day he meets during a period, with different start time and end time.

The example I used to assemble this is at this link: [Schedule Different Work Days](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/?_ga=2.217435473.674499638.1571572235-578596555.1563196694#/material/schedule/group-custom-work-days)

I am currently building a list of resources with these professionals and their days attending as follows:

```
 const resourceObject = {
    text: professional.name, id: professional.id,
    color: '#848484', workDays: days, startHour: '', endHour: ''
  };
```

I create a `resourceDataSource` list and add the above object inside it so that on the calendar I can know which days each professional attends.

My problem is that this way I can't set the start time and end time for a particular day.

**How can I maintain this programming logic by assigning different start and end times for certain days?**

```
{dayWork: 1, startTime: '13:00', endTime: '18:00', id: professionalId}
{dayWork 2, startTime: '08:00', endTime: '19:00', id: professionalId}
```

**component.html:**

```
<ng-template #resourceHeaderTemplate let-data>
    <div class='template-wrap'>
        <div class="avatar resource-image {{getDoctorImage(data)}}"></div>
        <div class="resource-details">
            <div class="resource-name">{{getDoctorName(data)}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<e-resources>
    <e-resource field='DoctorId' title='Professional' name='Doctors' [dataSource]='resourceDataSource'
        textField='text' idField='id' colorField='color' workDaysField='workDays' startHourField='startHour'
        endHourField='endHour'>
    </e-resource>
</e-resources>
```

Comment: you will probably not get help for this question... You should attempt some changes and ask questions once you are presented with errors or get stuck.

Comment: I did as it is in the example ... the only thing I need is to set start and end time for days specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion Greetings.

We have prepared the below sample to have different work hours per day for each resource using DataBinding and actionBegin events.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysiqa8-pzqfrc?file=app.component.ts

```
onDataBinding(args: any): void {
    if (this.flag) {
      if (
        this.scheduleObj.currentView !== "Month" &&
        this.scheduleObj.currentView !== "Agenda"
      ) {
        var currentViewDates = this.scheduleObj.getCurrentViewDates();
        for (var i = 0; i < currentViewDates.length; i++) {
          switch ((currentViewDates[i] as any).getDay()) {
            case 0:
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '06:00', '14:00', 0);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '08:00', '13:00', 1);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '07:00', '20:00', 2);
              break;
            case 1:
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '08:00', '14:00', 0);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '09:00', '13:00', 1);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '07:00', '20:00', 2);
              break;
            case 2:
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '07:00', '20:00', 0);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '08:00', '14:00', 1);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '09:00', '18:00', 2);
              break;
            case 3:
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '05:00', '10:00', 0);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '11:00', '15:00', 1);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '10:00', '14:00', 2);
              break;
            case 4:
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '10:00', '15:00', 0);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '08:00', '12:00', 1);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '09:00', '13:00', 2);
              break;
            case 5:
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '09:00', '14:00', 0);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '10:00', '19:00', 1);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '08:00', '18:00', 2);
               break;
            case 6:
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '07:00', '19:00', 0);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '08:00', '14:00', 1);
              this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours([currentViewDates[i]], '09:00', '20:00', 2);
          }
        }
      }
      this.flag = false;
    }

onActionBegin(args: ActionEventArgs): void {
        let isEventChange: boolean = (args.requestType === 'eventChange');
        if (args.requestType == "eventCreate" ||args.requestType == "eventChange" || args.requestType == "eventRemove" ) {
          this.flag = false;
        } else {
          this.flag = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You use the setWorkHours method with the last parameter which is the position of the professional, but which professional exactly is? Can I get which one is professional within the onDataBiding method?

Comment: Because I do not have a fixed position professional in my calendar, I have several professionals ... I have a filter to select which professionals I want to display, I need to know which professional is for me to get the start time and end time that belongs to him.

Comment: There is the getResourcesByIndex method but I need to know what resource it is currently running to get the pro, this is not within args.